# What kind of exterior wall insulation is this?

Tags: insulation

After some searching, I'm guessing it might be "encapsulated" insulation but I don't know. It's unmarked and, as you might see, it's it's tucked into the corner and bulging in the middle.

[image]

I assume that, despite the different type of insulation, it's still not right that they tucked it in like that.

Comment: Looks like it was installed by a non-pro after the wiring was done. Instead of burying the wiring in the insulation, they tucked it behind. It is odd that it's actually stapled to the side of the stud instead of the face...

Comment: It may be an additional layer of foil heat barrier, normally with heat barrier you don’t want those little gaps, some times you put like a furring strip on the ends. To help seal it for no air leakage.

Comment: @EdBeal It's stapled into the corners of the stud up against the outside sheathing which makes the insulation bulge out in the center. I'm assuming that's not the way it's supposed to be done. I'd hate to have to tear all that out and replace it. Otherwise I'd have to live with it. (It's a patio that was converted into a living room by the previous owner.)

Comment: It may not be the best install but why do you think you need to tear it out? Can you feel heat coming through?

Comment: I had to staple my insulation like this. The house had none when I bought it. Took internal walls down and stapled insulation to studs. To wrap the house properly would require taking external walls down as well which is not happening.

Comment: @EdBeal It's compressed which means I have very little to no insulation at the edges. I did not feel for heat coming through. The wall in the picture is south facing and gets a lot of sun.

Comment: That may be why they added the foil heat barrier , another good use for a thermal camera so you can see if there is a problem I have one I use it is good enough that I don’t have to pay for thermal inspections on my switch gear or load centers any longer , but I also use it to spot leaking ducts in attics and crawl spaces, do you know if you have 2x4 or 2x6 studs ? If 2x6 is so not really compressed .

Comment: @EdBeal it's 2x4

Comment: On 16” centers? It is tight but that doesn't mean  you have no insulation, I might staple down the spots on the 2x4 that are lifted stopping air movement is what the insulation dose without transmitting the heat from inside out or outside in. You might find you can tear it out and completely fill those stud bays and put up a new barrier and have very little difference. The difference will take a lifetime to pay for the materials and hours of work. I am being realistic about the difference having spent large amounts over a lifetime. No insulation or single Payne yes upgrade, extreme weather ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really seeing the part you're referring to with it being tucked in, but it looks to me like this is just foil-faced fiberglass batt insulation. The foil acts as a radiant energy barrier.

It is built like paper-faced insulation, but with a metallic facing instead of just paper. This is supposed to add some insulation value by reflecting energy back into the conditioned space or reflecting back to the outside, depending on how it's installed (you would face the foil inside if you mostly have to heat your interior, and outside if you mostly cool the interior).

Comment: On the sides, where the studs are. It's stapled into the edge where it meets the outside of the house.

Comment: Hard to say if it's not marked then. I guess if those are 2x6 studs and they used insulation for 2x4, it would at least not reduce the R value by squishing the insulation. But it's still probably better to install it as it should be, stapled to the faces of the studs.

Comment: I would agree it may even be a separate foil heat barrier, we did that on my uncles home in Mohave it makes a huge difference.